# What kind of micro bulb is this?

Tags: identification, automotive, light

I am doing a clone of my Honda's dashboard circuit. Everything is fine except I cannot find the tiny backlight bulbs (see photo) that are used for the dashboard button illumination. Are they standard bulbs that can be bought on Ebay? What would be the correct search term / part number for them then? Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Also, a few detached pics, they seem to be just glued on top of two contacts ([source - Lexus forums](http://us.lexusownersclub.com/forums/topic/69219-interior-and-exterior-bulbs-size/#entry432776)):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A pic of the whole bulb outside the pcb would be useful, assuming it is socketed

Comment: @PlasmaHH I updated the post with a few more pics.

Comment: Very likely a custom part, and if it is, good luck.

Comment: For whoever put this on hold as off-topic as "recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them", please reconsider. This is a standard part with a standard name and it has straightforward and useful application in PCB / electronics. Also, from the upvotes, it appears to be useful to more than myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms I'd use to describe them and to search for are "SMD incandescent lamp" or "surface mount incandescent lamp". Using those search terms I found a company called JKL Components that seems to have a range of [SMD Lamps](http://www.jkllamps.com/incandescent/smdlamps). I've never seen them stocked at more general suppliers so you might find them a bit tricky to track down.

Something you'll need to do (and should do when asking identification questions in general) is measure it's dimensions and the spacing between pins so you can check that anything you find will physically fit. It's worth double-checking but presumably they'd be driven from the 12V system so you'd want bulbs in the 12 - 14 V type range.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the part. Unfortunately, Ebay.com doesn't offer these square black housings that make it easy to glue/solder them on a PCB. There are a lot of just SMD bulbs (also called "wheat grain bulbs" for their size and shape) but none of these holders/sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell anything from just looking at the picture but a method to go may be to measure the voltage difference between two legs and just use another type of 'micro bulb' that would suit the voltage.

You can use the purple cap if interested or just paint it with a marker :)

Comment: Sure, as plan B. But what about those black plastic rectangular casings? They seem to be very convenient for housing a buld and glueing it into place. Have you seen anything like that around?